# InfluxDB forecasts with URL variables lower and upper - Upper not working

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to look at forecasts in a InfluxDB Dashboard via the URL with the lower and upper variables set to now() - 1d and now() + 2d. By my understanding the following URL should work but it keeps kicking back to the lower only.

http://localhost:8086/orgs/006d4ffde104016d/dashboards/089512ff1190f000?lower=now%28%29%20-%201d&upper=now%28%29%%20+%202d

What is the way to format the upper or is there another solution to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `upper` is only used when both it and `lower` are a static timestamp and not a `now - duration` format.